# How to streamline Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5

Excuse me, is so stupid question..

I use Controller, has many ORM , I want to  streamline this code.

my contorller

```
public function news(Request $request)
{
    $history = Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',1)->get();
    $history_a =  Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',2)->get();
    $history_b = Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',3)->get();  
    $history_c = Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',4)->get(); 
    $history_d = Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',5)->get(); 
    $history_e = Recruitments_status::where('recruitments_status.status',6)->get(); 

    return view('pl_sidebar/news',[
          'history' => $history,
          'history_a' => $history_a,
          'history_b' => $history_b,
          'history_c' => $history_c,
          'history_d' => $history_d,
          'history_e' => $history_e
    ]);
}
```

How to streamline the this ORM Code?

Comment: What is your aim in "streamlining" your code? What do you think is wrong? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wader thank you reply, my code is so long and many queries, I want streamlining this code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will generate multiple queries which is bad practice. You can get a collection:

```
public function news(Request $request)
{
    return view('pl_sidebar/news', [
        'history' => Recruitments_status::whereIn('status', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    ]);
}
```

Then in Blade template use this collection:

```
@foreach ($history->where('status', 1) as $single)
     {{ $single->status }}
     {{ $single->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: oh!　Thank you very much!  It is a great help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `whereIN`

```
  ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

so,

```
 $history = Recruitments_status::whereIn('recruitments_status.status',[1,2,3,4,5,6])->get();
```